# Записать товар с таким же id по разному вкусу в сессию, как новый

Tags: php, mysql, post

Добрый вечер!

Сейчас у меня товары в корзину летят так: если такой же id товара попал 2 раз в корзину, то просто прибавляется к нему количество введенное пользователем перед добавлением...

То есть сессия создает товары по его id, если новый id товара, то записывает новый товар... Но у меня есть поле вкусов, и сейчас, если пользователь выбрал разные вкусы одного и того же товара то просто этот вкус перезаписывается у этого товара, а мне нужно чтобы если выбран у этого же товара другой вкус, создать, как новый уже товар с этим же id.

Вот открываю сессию:

```
session_start();
```

далее: добавление в корзину, по нажатию на кнопку, получаю данные методом POST

```
 $goods_id = abs((int)$_POST['goods_id']); // id товара
 $qty = abs((int)$_POST['count']); // количество товара которое пришло

$vkysId = abs((int)$_POST['vkys']); // вкус товара, а именно значение  value
addtocart($goods_id, $vkysId, $qty); // передаем эти параметры
```

И вот на этом этапе скорее всего что-то нужно изменить:

```
function addtocart($goods_id, $vkysId, $qty){
    if(isset($_SESSION['cart'][$goods_id])){
        // если в массиве cart уже есть добавляемый товар
        $_SESSION['cart'][$goods_id]['qty'] += $qty;
        $_SESSION['cart'][$goods_id]['vkysId'] = $vkysId;
        return $_SESSION['cart'];
    }else{
        // если товар кладется в корзину впервые
        $_SESSION['cart'][$goods_id]['qty'] = $qty;
        $_SESSION['cart'][$goods_id]['vkysId'] = $vkysId;
        return $_SESSION['cart'];
    }
}
```

Сам пробовал прописать разные условия, не получилось, надеюсь на Вашу помощь:)

Распечатка на данный код вот:

```
[cart] => Array
        (
            [8] => Array
                (
                    [qty] => 4
                    [vkysId] => 2
                    [name] => Товар 1
                    [price] => 690
                    [img] => 8.jpg
                    [nalichies] => 3
         )
```

Остальные данные, если что я формирую в другой функции по пришедшему id.

**Добавил:**

```
function total_sum($goods){
    global $connection;
    $total_sum = 0;    
    $str_goods = implode(',',array_keys($goods));    
    $query = "SELECT goods_id, name, price, img, nalichies
                FROM goods
                    WHERE goods_id IN ($str_goods)";
    $res = mysqli_query($connection, $query) or die(mysqli_error());    
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)){
        $_SESSION['cart'][$row['goods_id']]['name'] = $row['name'];
        $_SESSION['cart'][$row['goods_id']]['price'] = $row['price'];
        $_SESSION['cart'][$row['goods_id']]['img'] = $row['img'];
        $_SESSION['cart'][$row['goods_id']]['nalichies'] = $row['nalichies'];
       if($row['nalichies'] > 0){
        $total_sum += $_SESSION['cart'][$row['goods_id']]['qty'] * $row['price'];
          }else{
            $total_sum += $_SESSION['cart'][$row['goods_id']]['qty'] * $row[0];
        }
    }
    return $total_sum;
}
```

Comment: Ваш массив должен стать `$_SESSION['cart'][$goods_id]['vkysId]'['qty']` Вот и все

Comment: @splash58, Покажите, пожалуйста, куда прописать это, не получается у меня. А лучше дайте ответ и в нем показав.

Answer (score 1):

Насколько я понимаю, должно быть так

```
function addtocart($goods_id, $vkysId, $qty){
    if(isset($_SESSION['cart'][$goods_id]['vkysId'])){
        // если в массиве cart уже есть добавляемый товар с тем же вкусом 
        $_SESSION['cart'][$goods_id]['qty']['vkysId']  += $qty;
    }else{
        // если сочетание товар-вкус кладется в корзину впервые
        $_SESSION['cart'][$goods_id]['qty']['vkysId'] = $qty;
    }
    return $_SESSION['cart'];
}
```

Comment: Выдает ошибку: **Fatal error: Unsupported operand types in N:\home\proekt.ru\www\model\model.php on line 123**
А именно это строка `$total_sum += $_SESSION['cart'][$row['goods_id']]['qty'] * $row['price'];`

Comment: Я кстати таким похожим способом пробовал)

Comment: Ну так теперь `$_SESSION['cart'][$row['goods_id']]['qty']` - массив с индексом из вкcуов. Листья массива должны еще один уровень индекса содержать `$_SESSION['cart'][$row['goods_id']]['qty']$_SESSION['cart'][$row['goods_id']]['qty']`

Comment: Я код добавил выше в котором выходит ошибка, посмотрите его, что-то я не особо понял про листья массива.

Comment: Так а вкусы там где?

Comment: дак они приходят из функции addtocart. Вы лучше добавьте в свой ответ исправленный код, потому что я дописываю и у меня не получается( Буду очень благодарен:)

Comment: Так, как  я понимаю, вам надо структуру базы данных менять. куда то же вкусы девать надо. И наличие надо различать для разных вкусов

Comment: И наличие надо различать для разных вкусов - это пока не нужно, главное что задал в вопросе)

Comment: Тогда в какой-то момент надо потерять этот индекс - вкус - просуммировав элементы. В какой, я не знаю, надо понимать структуру данных и интерфейсов

Comment: Спасибо за Вашу помощь!

Answer (score 0):

Очевидно для ссылки на товар в корзине надо использовать тот идентификатор, который реально уникально его идентифицирует. В торговле есть сложившийся термин: `SKU - единица складского учета`. В ней отражены варианты вроде вкуса или цвета - всех параметров, которые определяют выбор покупателя. У разных типов товара он может быть зависим от разных параметров.

Если вы будете пытаться использовать составной ключ типа (id, вкус), вы рано или поздно придете к тому, что его не хватает, т.к. важен еще и размер или цвет или что угодно. Поэтому начните сразу с определения SKU.

https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/SKU